# R while loop for fibonacci numbers smaller than 1 million

Tags: r, while-loop, fibonacci

Like the title says, I have to write a short block of code which saves the fibonacci numbers smaller than 1 million in a vector using a while-loop. The code I wrote runs for such a long time that I always have to stop the calculation process. I already have different code which solves the question but I am still unsure why this specific approach doesn't work?

what I tried:

```
fib <- c(0,1) #define starting numbers of fibonacci vector
n<-3 #starting index of calculated fibonacci numbers
while (max(fib)<10^6) { #highest fibonacci should be smaller than 1 million
  fib[n]<-fib[n-2]+fib[n-1] #definition of fibonacci sequence`
  n+1 
}
```

What I expected: vector with all fibonacci numbers smaller than 1 million
What actually happened: incredibly long run times so no real result

Comment: `n+1` should be `n <- n+1`

Comment: ... and hence you have an infinite loop.  Average run time of the corrected code on my system is 9 milliseconds.

Comment: You could lose the `n` completely and just do `fib <- c(fib, sum(tail(fib, 2)))` inside the loop

Comment: @Limey ... 9 milliseconds? Shoot, most of my iterations are under 200 microseconds! https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RQWF.png :-)

Comment: @r2evans My hardware is 13 years old <embarrassed face>.  What can I say...